# Get secret from Hashicorp Vault private cluster from Gitlab CI/CD job

Tags: gitlab-ci, hashicorp-vault

We are in the process of setting up Hashicorp Vault for our pipeline secrets using the GitLab integration. Currently, we are using GitLab.com to host our code and start pipelines. We have a few runners that are registered there, but we mostly used their shared runners. The vault is hosted by Hashicorp Cloud.

When the Vault network accessibility is in public mode, everything works fine. However, we want to secure our setup as much as possible and having the vault network in private mode sounds like what we want.

However, I cannot find clear information on how to allow the pipeline to contact the private Vault. What should we do to make it work?

Comment: "private" mode? There is development and production modes, with `-dev` switch. Have you read https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/#configure-your-vault-server

Comment: @KamilCuk I am referring to the "Network accessibility" option in Hashicorp Cloud

I read the documentation you provided, but maybe I missed something? I'll go through it again,

Comment: We'll need to know a bit more about your setup.  This sounds like a network issue more than a CI/CD issue.  Is your GitLab instance the public gitlab.com one?  Are your running/managing your own?  Is your Vault server on a cloud provider or on-prem?

Comment: @GlenYu We are using gitlab.com, not our own instance. We mostly use shared runners provided by Gitlab, but we also have a few that we run ourselves in Azure. The vault server is from Hashicorp Cloud. I'll also add those details to the question.

Comment: Though I agree that this is more of a network problem

Comment: Is your HCP Vault on Azure or AWS?   I'm not much of an Azure person, but for AWS you can have security_groups to allow IP ranges/ports.  And while I have used Gitlab, I've mostly used self-managed ones where I know the IP CIDRs of my runners etc.  I would say to maybe make your HCP Vault public and then configure the fw/security groups to allow ingress only for [these ranges](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ip-range) (plus your own) and see if that works and experiment from there....?

Comment: @GlenYu It is on Azure. I would guess I need to [setup a connection between HCP and our Azure network](https://developer.hashicorp.com/hcp/tutorials/networking/azure-peering-hcp#azure-peering-hcp) to do that?

Comment: No, that's not it.  If you setup peering, that only allows connection from your private HCP Vault to your own Azure VPC --- but that's not where your GitLab is sitting.  You're using the (public) gitlab.com one.  So you need to make your HCP Vault public and then lock down what IPs can reach that public endpoint.   As the HCP Vault is also sitting in a managed VPC, I don't know if you have access to make changes to that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252573/discussion-between-glen-yu-and-thebird956).